# Are Apache Camel Mbeans extendable?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jmx, mbeans

I would like to add few more attributes to the existent JMX Apache Camel route attributes. Is there a way of doing this either using Spring or Java code?

Comment: Camel is open source on git, can't you simply rebuild with your specific fields added?

Comment: What kind of information do you want to add? Maybe its useable for others and we can add it out of the box?

Comment: I will explain how I did it in my next response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And to answer your question. No the routes mbean are not extensible.

Though if you build custom components you can annotate your component with JMX annotations to have JMX operations and attributes enlisted out of the box. But this is only for components, and not the standard route, camelcontext, mbeans etc.

See details at: http://camel.apache.org/camel-jmx.html